# How to rename certain key names in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

This is my object:

```
{
    "title": "title",
    "Components": [{
        "title": "component 1",
        "id": 0,
        "contents": {
            "1": {
                "title": "sub-component 1",
                "sub_contents": {
                    "1": {
                        "title": "blah",
                    }
                }
            },
           "2": {
                "title": "sub-component 1",
                "sub_contents": {
                    "3": {
                        "title": "blah",
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

The objects in the sub_contents object each start with a property that is a number. The program in question requires those numbers to be in sequence across the whole JSON. As you can see it starts sub_contents -> 1 then goes sub_contents -> 3. I need to write a function that traverses the whole thing and re-sequences them all starting with 1. I am really unsure of how to do this. I seem to be able to get the name of the key but not set it.

My code:

```
function reindex_manifest(manifest){
var index = 1;

        $.each(manifest.Components, function(i) {
            $.each(manifest.Components[i].contents, function(n) {
                var obj = manifest.Components[i].contents[n].sub_contents;
                for (var key in obj) {
                    // I CAN READ THE KEY HERE BUT HOW DO I CHANGE IT TO THE
                    //   VALUE OF THE INDEX VARIABLE??
                    console.log(key);
                }
             });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***One quick approach is:***

**You need to remove the old key, duplicate the key-value pair with the new given key name, and inject it back to your object**.

Also, to make this happen without causing conflicts, you need to switch away from `each` where you can't mutate the variable. See my example below:

```
function reindex_manifest(manifest){ 
    for (var i in manifest.Components){
        var contentKeys = Object.keys(manifest.Components[i].contents);
        for (var k of contentKeys){

            var content = manifest.Components[i].contents[k];
            var subcontent = manifest.Components[i].contents[k].sub_contents;

            // Check the subcontent key agains the content key
            var subcontent_key = Object.keys(subcontent)[0];
            if (subcontent_key !== k){
               // Re-sequence it, and replace the old one
               subcontent[k] = subcontent[subcontent_key];
               subcontent[subcontent_key] = null;
               delete subcontent[subcontent_key];

               // Update the root
               manifest.Components[i].contents[k].sub_contents = subcontent;
            }
        }
    }

}
```